# Division stops working for negative numbers

Tags: c++

I made it  display the Dividend so that people can decipher the code without much hassle. It worked once but then I don't know what I did to make it stop working. It works perfectly for positive integers. It is supposed to display the number associated with user input.

```
#include <iostream>                                        // Necessary header
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   signed int Input, Divisor, Dividend, MSD;

   cout << "Input:";
   cin >> Input;

   Divisor = 1;
   Dividend = Input;
   if (Input < 0)
   {
       Dividend *= -1;
       cout << "minus ";
   }

   cout << Dividend;
   while (Dividend > 9)
   {
       Divisor = Divisor * 10;
       Dividend = Dividend / 10;
   }

   while (Divisor != 0)
   {
       MSD = Input / Divisor;
       switch (MSD)
       {
           case 0:
           cout << "zero ";
           break;
           case 1:
           cout << "one ";
           break;
           case 2:
           cout << "two ";
           break;
           case 3:
           cout << "three ";
           break;
           case 4:
           cout << "four ";
           break;
           case 5:
           cout << "five ";
           break;
           case 6:
           cout << "six ";
           break;
           case 7:
           cout << "seven ";
           break;
           case 8:
           cout << "eight ";
           break;
           case 9:
           cout << "nine ";
           break;
       }
    Input = Input - (MSD * Divisor);
    Divisor /= 10;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
if (Input < 0)
{
    Dividend *= -1;
    cout << "minus ";
}
```

to

```
if (Input < 0)
{
    Input *= -1;
    cout << "minus ";
}
```

But really, did you debug?:)

Comment: @user1728737 Good, but try to debug next time! By the way, you don't mark questions as accepted (2 other questions with right answers in your profile), that's a very bad habit here. You are welcome. :)

Comment: No. I didn't debug but I will from now on. Hold on I'm trying to mark as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code does not work for negative numbers. Look at this line:

```
while (Divisor != 0) {
    MSD = Input / Divisor;
    // switch statement
}
```

If the user enters a negative value for `Input`, no case will be hit in your switch statement. I believe you want to make sure you use the absolute value of `Input`, rather than what the user entered.

Comment: *I think your code does not work for negative numbers.* Exactly. It's not division that's not working correctly. It's the code that isn't working correctly.

Comment: That works once I fixed Input = -Input in the if statement. I didn't need to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Works! Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>                                        // Necessary header
using namespace std;
const int DIV = 10;                                        // Avoid Magic Numbers
const int REM = 9;

int main()
{
   signed int Input, Divisor, Dividend, MSD;               // Signed because negative values need to be read

   cout << "Input:";
   cin >> Input;
   cout << "Output: ";

   if (Input < 0)                                          // If the input is negative, make it positive
   {
      Input = -Input;
      cout << "minus ";
   }

   Divisor = 1;                                            // Initialize Divisor to 1
   Dividend = Input;                                       // Dividend is equal to input number
   while (Dividend > REM)
   {
      Divisor *= DIV;
      Dividend /= DIV;
   }

   while (Divisor != 0)                                    // While the Divisor is not 0
   {
      MSD = Input / Divisor;                               // The most significant digit is obtained
      switch (MSD)
      {
         case 0:                                           // Multiple cases to print all digits 0 to 9
            cout << "zero ";
            break;
         case 1:
            cout << "one ";
            break;
         case 2:
            cout << "two ";
            break;
         case 3:
            cout << "three ";
            break;
         case 4:
            cout << "four ";
            break;
         case 5:
            cout << "five ";
            break;
         case 6:
            cout << "six ";
            break;
         case 7:
            cout << "seven ";
            break;
         case 8:
            cout << "eight ";
            break;
         case 9:
            cout << "nine ";
            break;
      }
      Input -= MSD * Divisor;                              // Change input so next digit can be obtained
      Divisor /= DIV;
   }
   return 0;
}                                                          // End main method
```